# Product of $3$ normal variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random variable is normally distributed with a mathematical expectation of $3$ and a variance of $9$. Find the probability that the product of $3$ such variables will be negative.

I am most interested in whether the product of $3$ normal variables is also a normal variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The product of $k>1$ independent normals is not normally distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y,Z\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\mathcal{N}(3,9)$ then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(XYZ<0) &= \mathbb P(X<0,Y>0,Z>0) + \mathbb P(X<0,Y<0,Z>0) + \mathbb P(X<0,Y<0,Z<0) +\mathbb P(X<0,Y<0,Z<0)\\
&=\mathbb P(X<0)\mathbb P(Y>0)\mathbb P(Z>0) + \mathbb P(X>0)\mathbb P(Y<0)\mathbb P(Z>0) + \mathbb P(X>0)\mathbb P(Y>0)\mathbb P(Z<0) + \mathbb P(X<0)\mathbb P(Y<0)\mathbb P(Z<0)\\
&= 3\mathbb P(X<0)\mathbb P(X>0)^2 + \mathbb P(X<0)^3\\
&= 3\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac1{\sqrt{18\pi}} e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-3}3\right)^2} \ \mathsf dx \left(\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{18\pi}} e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-3}3\right)^2} \ \mathsf dx\right)^2 + \left(\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac1{\sqrt{18\pi}} e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-3}3\right)^2} \ \mathsf dx\right)^3\\
&= \frac{3}{8} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)^2 \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3\right)\\
&\approx 0.3409112
\end{align}

Comment: Your denominator $9$s need to be $3$s, so you'll need to recalculate everything. You should find a lower answer.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot that I included $\sigma^2$ in the square there instead of $\sigma$. I did use $\texttt{PDF[NormalDistribution[3,9],x]}$ in Mathematica to compute the integrals though, so the result didn't change.

Comment: Oh, I see - $\texttt{NormalDistribution}$ takes $\mu$ and $\sigma$, not $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. It should be correct now.

Comment: @Math1000: Thank you so much!  You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u \in \mathbb{R}$, you dont specify if you multiply $3$ different variables, but let's look at that case $U=X^3$ where $X$ is the normal variable you defined.

The cdf of $U$ is given by

$$F_U(u)=P(X^3 \leq u)=P(X \leq u^{\frac13})=F_X(u^{\frac13})$$

The density function of $U$ is therefore

$$f_U(u)=F_U'(u)=\frac13u^{-\frac23}f_X(u^{\frac13})$$

There is no need to expand the density function, the presence of the term $u^{-\frac23}$ automatically rejects that $X^3$ is a normal distribution.